# Access to https on Amazon AWS S3 (5GB free) - Virtual Hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I try access to Amazon AWS S3 with https.

This link with http works: http://sc-st01.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

But this not: https://sc-st01.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

Is there any setting to enable it?

I use CNAME also but i think the problem is in access to https.

Thank you for any advice.

UPDATE: This refers to using S3 to host static web content.

Comment: What does your CNAME record looks like? Try with https://`s3-<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>`

Comment: I use sc-st01.domain.com to sc-st01.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com I think this isnt cname problem, becouse http works.

Comment: Try with `https://s3-<region>.amazonaws.com/<domain>/<bucket-name>` or just `https://s3-<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>`

Comment: You help me little. I try https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sc-st01 and result was: <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>7574AD6DDDBAB13D</RequestId>
<HostId>
Q/wNxOJJ3Q1sXv5Rw/x9NiNVRW9ELfe6JG3UmD42BN7+Y/Goj7WcktqTy/DWlgLJK8RMILqr2V0=
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: Ah.. you're using S3 to host static web content, right? I thought you meant how to direct access object in your bucket via HTTPS. Are you using aws cloudfront?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using your S3 bucket to host static web content, then HTTPS isn't supported. To quote the AWS [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html), it says under the *Test your website* section:

> Note
>
> HTTPS access to the website is not supported.

Not very helpful. If you are interested in learning how S3 virtual hosting works, you can read more about it [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html).

To serve your static web content over HTTPS, you will need to set up an [AWS CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) distribution, which is quite straight forward via the AWS Management Console. The only configurations that will require special attentions are:

- `Origin Domain Name`: This should refer to the URI of your S3 bucket. In your case, it will be `sc-st01.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`
- `Viewer Protocol Policy`: Default to `HTTP and HTTPS Only`
- `Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)`: CNAME you set up in your DNS.
- `SSL Certificate`: Either `Default CloudFront Certificate` or `Custom SSL Certificate` if you have one. Note that setting up custom SSL certificate is more involved as it needs to be uploaded to the IAM.
- `Default Root Object`: The default file you want to serve when your user visits your static web site.

Once you're done with setting up the configurations, it will usually take 5 to 10 minutes for the new distribution to be fully configured and set up. Refer the `Status` field on the CloudFront management dashboard for progress. When ready, you will see the new `Domain Name` of your distribution. You should be able to access the static web content in your S3 bucket (assuming that the permissions of the content is granted to `Everyone`) by navigating to the `http:` or `https://` URL of your distribution `Domain Name`.

I will also recommend checking out the CloudFront [pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/) to ensure if you are aware of what is free, and what isn't.

Comment: @Maximi Glad it helps. Would you mind upvoting the answer too? Thanks!